# SQL Default CONSTRAINT not working

Tags: sql-server, constraint

I have the table below with some basic information with two defaulted columns

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INSPECTION](
    [InspectionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentStateTypeID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [CurrentStateTypeDefault]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DState] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DStateDefault]  DEFAULT ((9)))
```

When I try to insert a record with incomplete information into this table however, I'm getting an error

SQL for INSERT: `INSERT INTO INSPECTION ([LocationID]) VALUES (1);`

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CurrentStateTypeID', table
>   'DatabaseName.dbo.Inspection'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

I would think with the default, I would get a record with an Inspection of the next number (from the Identity), a LocationID of 1, a CurrentStateTypeID of 0, and a DState of 9.

There is also a trigger on the table which works with the CurrentStateTypeID after Insert, but I would think that would happen after the insert and it's defaulted values.

Trigger Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[StateTypeUpdate] ON [dbo].[INSPECTION]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(CurrentStateHistoryID)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @inspectionId int
   DECLARE @stateHistoryId int
   DECLARE @InspectionIDString varchar(max)
   SET @inspectionId = (SELECT InspectionId FROM Inserted)
   SET @stateHistoryId = (SELECT CurrentStateHistoryId FROM Inserted)
   SET @InspectionIDString = CONVERT(varchar(25), @inspectionId)
   EXEC WritePENGSHistoryRecord @stateHistoryId, @InspectionIDString
END
END
```

Comment: What you have works fine for me, so please (a) confirm it's the trigger by temporarily disabling it, and then (b) post the code for the trigger, since that's where the problem is.

Comment: I've added the Trigger code. Disabling the Trigger did fix the problem temporarily

Comment: (1) What is the expected behavior of this trigger when you insert two rows in a single statement? (2) What does the procedure do? Does it write to the same table? Did you obscure the table name with `XXXXX` because in fact this is a different table?

Comment: I obscured the table name because it was fully qualified with the database name. Technically its "DataBaseName.dbo.Inspection" We only insert a single record at a time for this table so the trigger wasn't designed to handle multiple inserts at the same time. The trigger calls a procedure with some shared code for a handful of different processes. Both the trigger and the procedure worked until I changed the two columns to non-nullable and added the defaults.

Comment: You never have to worry about the thing you didn't test for until someone does it. Also, `SELECT CurrentStateHistoryId FROM Inserted` fails because that column isn't in `Inspection`. So either your table definition isn't right, or you have some logic in the wrong order.

Comment: The table technically has something like 40 other columns I cut out of the table definition above because they weren't really relevant to the issue, including CurrentStateHistoryId

Comment: Well you're passing CurrentStateHistoryId to the other procedure, and you're checking if that value changed, so maybe it is relevant. I still fail how to see how that trigger is raising the error you posted - and suspect the `Write...` stored procedure is causing that issue. If you take the stored procedure call out of the trigger, I bet it magically starts working again too.